# Zip and Retrieve the ArrayList on the fly

Tags: java, gzip

I have a charting application, as shown below.

Once the user has made a request for 10 Year Data (through the slider or through using from and to date fields), I am querying a MySQL database for getting chart data. The data will be in an ArrayList. As the data is very large, can I zip that data using java GZIP to transfer it from DAO to the servlet?

Or will it be an extra burden?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A [`GZIPOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) can accept an `OutputStream`, so 'yes'.

> ..will it be an extra burden?

In CPU cycles when zipping/unzipping, yes.  For the actual transfer it should be a significantly lighter burden (which I suspect is the bottleneck you wish to circumvent).